# the header fields of an HTTP message: who chooses them?

Tags: http, http-headers

Looking at the network panel in the developer tools of google chrome I can read the HTTP request and response messages of each file in a web page and, in particular, I can read the start line and the headers with all their fields.

I know (and I hope that is right) that the start line of each HTTP message has a specific and rigorous structure (different for request and response message, of course) and any element inside a start line cannot be missed.

Unlike the start line, the header of an HTTP message contains additional informations, so, I guess, the header fields are facultative or, at least, not so strictly requested like the fields in the start line.

Considering all this, I'm wondering: who sets the header fields in an HTTP message? Or, in other words, how are determined the header fields of an HTTP message?

For example, i can actually see that the HTTP request message for a web page is this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.corriere.it
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,de;q=0.2
Cookie: rccsLocalPref=milano%7CMilano%7C015146; rcsLocalPref=milano%7CMilano; _chartbeat2=DVgclLD1BW8iBl8sAi.1422913713367.1430683372200.1111111111111111; rlId=8725ab22-cbfc-45f7-a737-7c788ad27371; __ric=5334%3ASat%20Jun%2006%202015%2014%3A13%3A31%20GMT+0200%20%28ora%20legale%20Europa%20occidentale%29%7C; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1433680191192r0.8780217287130654; optimizelySegments=%7B%222207780387%22%3A%22gc%22%2C%222230660652%22%3A%22false%22%2C%222231370123%22%3A%22referral%22%7D; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; __gads=ID=bbe86fc4200ddae2:T=1434976116:S=ALNI_MZnWxlEim1DkFzJn-vDIvTxMXSJ0g; fbm_203568503078644=base_domain=.corriere.it; apw_browser=3671792671815076067.; channel=Direct; apw_cache=1438466400.TgwTeVxF.1437740670.0.0.0...EgjHfb6VZ2K4uRK4LT619Zau06UsXnMdig-EXKOVhvw; ReadSpeakerSettings=enlarge=enlargeoff; _ga=GA1.2.1780902850.1422986273; __utma=226919106.1780902850.1422986273.1439110897.1439114180.19; __utmc=226919106; __utmz=226919106.1439114180.19.18.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); s_cm_COR=Googlewww.google.it; gvsC=New; rcsddfglr=1441375682.3.2.m0i10Mw-|z1h7I0wH.3671792671815076067..J3ouwyCkNXBCyau35GWCru0I1mfcA3hRLNURnDWREPs; cpmt_xa=5334,5364; utag_main=v_id:014ed4175b8e000f4d2bb480bdd10606d001706500bd0$_sn:74$_ss:1$_st:1439133960323$_pn:1%3Bexp-session$ses_id:1439132160323%3Bexp-session; testcookie=true; s_cc=true; s_nr=1439132160762-Repeat; SC_LNK_CR=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; dtLatC=116p80.5p169.5p91.5p76.5p130.5p74p246.5p100p74.5p122.5; dtCookie=E4365758C13B82EE9C1C69A59B6F077E|Corriere|1|_default|1; dtPC=-; NSC_Wjq_Dpssjfsf_Dbdif=ffffffff091a1f8d45525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660; hz_amChecked=1
```

how these header fields are chosen? Who/what chose them? (The browser? Not me, of course...)

p.s.: 
hope my question is clear, please, forgive my bad english

Comment: I suggest you start reading some documentation of the http protocol.

Comment: How a value of a field is determined depends on (at a minimum) which field you are talking about. Often several different people / pieces of software could have influence over it. Your question doesn't really seem to be a good fit for Stackoverflow: ["Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced."](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @arkascha thank you for your suggestion and I'm doing it, in the meantime I would be happy to find a reply to my question.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you wondering whether the HTTP request headers can be decided by something other than your browser? A dwarf residing inside your PC, perhaps?

Comment: What's this "start line" you refer to? You appear to use the term ambiguously.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit — I think he means the Request Line

Comment: I don't understand that comment you replied to me. The documentation defines what headers are and who sends them: the client sends the request headers. Your client is your browser. So the browser sends the request headers. Take a look at the extensions for your browsers. There should be some that allow you to play around with custom headers. Might be of interest.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit here is a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) of all the possible header fields for a request message: the question is, why the broser chooses only some of them?

Comment: @Quentin yes, the Request Line

Comment: @arkascha read the question that I made to LightnessRacesinOrbit, it's the same that i would make to you.

Comment: @marco: It's complicated. There are some things it doesn't care about, doesn't need. A full discussion of why some particular browser will choose some particular headers for some particular request to some particular server on some particular computer on some particular day could fill a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> here is a list of all the possible header fields for a request message: the question is, why the broser chooses only some of them?

The browser doesn't include all possible request headers in every request because either:

- They aren't applicable to the current request *or*
- The default value is the desired value

For instance:

`Accept` tells the server that only certain data formats are acceptable in the response. If any kind of data is acceptable, then it can be omitted as the default is "everything".

`Content-Length` describes the length of the body of the request. A GET request doesn't have a body, so there is nothing to describe the length of.

`Cookie` contains a cookie set by the server (or JavaScript) on a previous request. If a cookie hasn't been set, then there isn't one to send back to the server.

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

All internet websites are hosted on [HTTP servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), these headers are set by the http server who is hosting the webpage. They are used to control how pages are shown, cached, and encoded.

Web browsers set the headers when requesting the pages from the servers. This mutual communication protocol is the HTTP protocol linked above.

Comment: The question is about response headers, not request headers.

Comment: The OP showed only an *example* of a request, linking his knowledge to HTTP protocol is the answer.

Comment: The answer is still incomplete then, since the HTTP server doesn't set the request headers.

Comment: the question is about both request and response headers. 
Anyway, I can understand that maybe for the response header the HTTP server is responsible of the header fields, but what about the request header and its fields? How the browsers choose some fields ignoring others?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer - the browser sets the request HTTP headers when it requests web pages from the server.